# Ubuntu btrfs snapshot cannot mv into /home

Tags: ubuntu, restore, snapshot, btrfs

I want to be able to take a snapshot and restore it in real time.

This works in Fedora and does a live "rollback" :

```
btrfs subvolume snapshot /home /home/snapshot
mv /home/snapshot /home
```

But in Ubuntu it just says that it can't move to the same place.
It will agree to move the snapshot folder elsewhere inside `/home`, but not to replace it.

Is there a way to get around the problem ?

Comment: I wouldn't blame Ubuntu for refusing to execute this mv command. You should maybe place the snapshot not inside the same folder that you are trying to replace.

Comment: I know it looks strange, but it worked on fedora.

Comment: Ubuntu might be doing the mv in a more intelligent/optimized manner than Fedora.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `btrfs subvolume list | grep /home`, `mount | grep /home`, `df | grep /home` and `uname -a`, from both systems (clearly tagged so we can tell which one is which). This smells to me very much like either a kernel version (capability) difference or a file system hierarchy difference. (The `btrfs` command may require adjusting, but the idea is to get a list of btrfs' idea of what your /home and anything below it looks like.)

Comment: Why don't you divide this into 2 steps : (1) `cp /home/snapshot /home`, (2) `rm -r -f /home/snapshot`?

Comment: I found a way with rsync thaks

Comment: @user244986 : Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evidently, Ubuntu might be doing the mv in a different manner than Fedora,
which is why it is rejecting an operation that requires deleting the source of the move.
This is most probably an over-strong check for correctness in the mv program,
since a file-by-file move should succeed under Ubuntu as well as under Fedora.

The solution is to do the operation in two steps :

1. Copy/resync the folder `/home/snapshot` to `/home`
2. Remove the folder `/home/snapshot` (if really required).